# Ubuntu wont show in Windows bootloader

Tags: windows-xp

I have installed ubuntu 14.04. I want to get back to windows xp to check something. However grub wouldnt let me. So i got boot repair on ubuntu. I then changed the boot drive from this drive (ubuntu) to windows md5 something. Now i dont know how to get back onto ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

boot from ubuntu live disk , follow steps here ([Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair))

[image]

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8038275/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8038275/

Comment: i already did the recommended boot repair.